# Maven Dependency -- Throws load() exception

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I am creating a new project in Java using Maven. I'll have to use Mongo and Hadoop. but when i use the following dependency and try to run the application by using tomcat:run I am getting Throws load() exception .

The dependency is

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-hadoop-core_1.0.2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and the error is :

**SEVERE: Servlet /MongoRESTApi threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet**

How can I solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you already look through the various SO posts which come up on google for this very same error message?

Comment: yea. but I din't get any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably encountering the [jar hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell) issue:

> A developer or deployer of a Java application has accidentally made
>   two different versions of a library available to the system.

The mongo-hadoop-core_1.0.2 dependency may have introduced further transitive dependencies; probably a second servlet-api which you need to [exclude](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).
Finding the erroneous dependencies may be tedious, therefore I'd suggest you to include the [JBoss Tattletale](http://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/userguide/1.2/en-US/html/maven.html) plugin in your build phase. Configure the `multiplejars` report and *enable* `failOnWarn` and `failOnError`. The generated report will list those classes which can be found in multiple jars. From this you'll see which dependencies should be excluded to escape from jar hell.